# Dealing with multiple routes that take IDs

Tags: c#, .net

I am just wondering how I would deal with a route with multiple ids. For example, I have two controllers called "Movies" and "Rentals". I have the requests laid out for `/rentals`, but I want the routes for Movies to be `/rentals/{rentalId}/movies` so that I can have the movies that were included in the rental and to go more in depth I want to do `/rentals/{rentalId}/movies/{movieId}`. Are there any examples to help me get started?

Comment: You can simply define the route just like you said, /rentals/{rentalId}/movies/{movieId}. Specify this path in the route attribute and take rentalId movieId as arguments in your function implementing the endpoint.

Comment: @AvivAviv will the specific movies show up for the rental or will I have to add additional code in a repository to make it more specific?

Comment: Yes, to implement /rentals/{rentalId}/movies/{movieId} you need your repository to be able to quary by rentalId and movieId. Also, I forgot to say that I recommend that the new endpoint of yours will be in the rentals controller (even tho it also queries by the movie) not for technical reasons but simply because of the convention.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the MVC default routing template, this would be harder to achieve.

**Default Template (I hate it)**:
app.MapControllerRoute(
name: "default",
pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

I prefer to use the **Attribute Routing**, so I can have absolute control over the routing, even spliting into multiple files, you can have them set up like you need. But you can check for more details, depending on the .net version you're using.

Good read:
[https://www.infoworld.com/article/3569369/how-to-use-attribute-routing-in-aspnet-core.html#:~:text=You%20can%20set%20up%20routing,your%20action%20methods%20with%20attributes](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3569369/how-to-use-attribute-routing-in-aspnet-core.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%20set%20up%20routing,your%20action%20methods%20with%20attributes).